# Setting distance range in spatial join using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, polygon, distance, spatial-join, select

I have many city polygons and I want to select some of them with distance range condition from boundary of other polygons.  I use WITHIN_A_DISTANCE in spatial join but this item selects even intersected city  boundary.

How can I set distance range for example 0 up to 3 km from city boundary?

Comment: How are you performing your spatial join? By the dialog in the context menu or by the toolbox geoprocessing tool.